# Changing state using ternary operator inside useState() not worknig

Tags: reactjs

I want to changes state i.e replace Select field with simple text field when clicked on a button.

```
var [selectOptions, setSelectOptions] = useState(true);
const [showFromFirst, setSwitch] = useState([
<div className="form-group">
  <label>From</label>
  <div>
    <Field name="from" />
  </div>
</div>,
<div className="form-group">
  <label>Destination</label>

  {selectOptions ? (
    <Field
      as="select"
      name="destination"
      className="form-control form-control-sm"
    >
      <option>Zone 3</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </Field>
  ) : (
    <Field name="destination" component={LocationSearchInput} />
  )}

  <div id="map" />
</div>,
 ]);
```

Now when I change the value of selectOptions with onClick(), it gets changed(to false) but change is not reflected inside state i.e UI remains the same.
Kindly help me. Thank You.

Comment: Seems like you have a problem with your code :) Why you have html into state?

Comment: Because I need to change the the positions of certain ui sections dynamically when clicked on a certain button that's why

Comment: You must not store JSX in state but variables that control the rendering. If you want to change positions, you can create an array of data and render them

Comment: Just add if else statement and render what you want depends on state or some other condition.

Comment: That's what I have done as you can see in the above code (I used ternary operator)

Comment: Ternary operator is inside the state being used and state is not updated unless you use `setSwitch` so when you think that setOptions will update `showFromFirst` you are wrong. It will only happen if you do not store it in state but directly render it

Comment: but I cannot render it directly because I also need to switch (UI)sections, that's why I need to store it in state so that I can easily switch places. What else do you suggest??

Answer (score 1):

it's really not a good idea to store html in state

separate into the return part and then toggle state to render different stuff

```
const component = () => {
  const [selectOptions, setSelectOptions] = useState([])

 return (
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>From</label>
    <div>
      <Field name="from" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div onClick={() =>setSelectOptions(!selectOptions)}>Toggle state here</div>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>Destination</label>

    {selectOptions ? (
      <Field
        as="select"
        name="destination"
        className="form-control form-control-sm"
      >
        <option>Zone 3</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </Field>
    ) : (
      <Field name="destination" component={LocationSearchInput} />
    )}
    <div id="map" />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I have stored the jsx ino variables but my issue is the same...It is still not changing the ui.

Comment: you need to toggle the ui based on `state`. if the state changes, it'll render the different ui